# Extracting xpath values in Logstash to conditionally create new fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

The structure of my  xml file is attahced below . I want to extract the value of field created by xpath and run a if else condition on it. In a way that if that if value of station_name is equal to "Finch" then create a new field and store in it.Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this

A codified version of what I am trying to achieve

```
if "Finch" in [station_name] {
xpath => ["/station/name/text()","Ny_station"]
}
else {
xpath => ["/station/name/text()","nonNy_station"]
}
```

Here is my config file

```
input
{
file
{
path => "C:\Users\186181152\Downloads\stations3.xml"
start_position => "beginning"
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
exclude => "*.gz"
type => "xml"
codec => multiline {
     pattern => "<stations>" 
     negate => "true"
     what => "previous"
}
}
}
filter
{
xml
{
source => "message"
store_xml => false
target => "stations"
xpath => [
"/stations/station/id/text()", "station_id",
"/stations/station/name/text()", "station_name"
]
}

}

output
{
elasticsearch
{
codec => json
hosts => "localhost"
index => "xmlns24"
}
stdout
{
codec => rubydebug
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field to add fields.

Comment: I might have not understood your question right, but that how I would do it: `if "Finch" in [station_name] { mutate{ add_field => {"Ny_station" => "%{station_name}"} } } else { mutate{ add_field => {"nonNy_station" => "%{station_name}"} } }`

Comment: @baudsp Thanks that worked for me. Also, I want to ask one more thing can I run the if else loop in the xml filter. I tried that and it did not work out.

Comment: I don't think that's possible to run the if else loop in the xml filter. But you can have two xml filter in the if else loop. I'll add an answer with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't the if else loop in the xml filter. But you can have two xml filter and in the if else loop, with the only difference being the variable created by the xpath.

Here it checks the string `Finch` as a regex  pattern against the message value to decide which xml filter to use.

```
if [message] =~ "Finch" {
    xml
    {
        source => "message"
        store_xml => false
        target => "stations"
        xpath => [
            "/stations/station/id/text()", "station_id",
            "/stations/station/name/text()", "Ny_station"
        ]
    }
} else {
    {
        source => "message"
        store_xml => false
        target => "stations"
        xpath => [
            "/stations/station/id/text()", "station_id",
            "/stations/station/name/text()", "nonNy_station"
        ]
    }
}
```